# How can source Int16Array values be retained though conversion to Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams, typed-arrays

I pass data through functions in this format

```
Int16Array > Uint8Array > Int16Array
```

How to make z be the same as the original x

```
var x = new Int16Array([17, -45]);
var y = new Uint8Array(x);
var z = new Int16Array(y);
```

Want to make z as `[ 17, -45 ]`

EDIT:
FULL EXAMPLE

```
const Readable = require('stream').Readable;

const rs = new Readable({
    objectMode: false,
    read(){}
});

var data = new Int16Array([17, -45]);
rs.push(data);

rs.on('data', function(chunk) {
    var result = new Int16Array(chunk);
});
```

I want "result" to have value `[17, -45]`

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Why are you doing a conversion at all if the end result in a `Int16Array` again? Clearly, converting to an `Uint8Array` doesn't work since it'll loose half of the information.

Comment: Only converting because callback complains. The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of Int16Array

Comment: @moimoi What callback are you talking about? Please [edit] your question to include the actual code that you have problems with.

Comment: @moimoi it's not beneath me to answer, but it should be beneath you to ask without showing any effort (as usual on SO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

| Number | 16 bit (BE) | In binary (BE) | Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | `0x00 0x11` | `00000000 00010001` |  |
| -45 | `0xff 0xd3` | `11111111 11010011` | `255,211` in decimal |
| 45 | `0x00 0xd3` | `00000000 00101101` | The bits are flipped |

A 16 bit TypedArray with two values in it would need `2 * Int16Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT = 4` bytes to store data. You can check that yourself:

```
console.log(
  arr16 = new Int16Array([17, -45]),
  arr16.buffer
);

[17, -45] // two elements (decimal)
...<11 00 d3 ff> // of 4 bytes total
```

*Note: `11 00` & `d3 ff` as opposed to `00 11` & `ff d3`. The order is different because the representation is Little Endian. Don't worry about that.*

If you pass the `buffer` to a `Int8Array`, you'd get:

```
console.log(
  arr8 = new Uint8Array( arr16.buffer ),
  arr8.buffer
);

[17, 0, 211, 255] // four elements (decimal)
...<11 00 d3 ff> // but same 4 bytes total
```

*Note: In fact arr8 and arr16 both refer to the **exact** same bytes, so if you do `arr16[0]=3`, `arr8[0]` will change, too!*

The inverse is not that hard to imagine now:

```
new Int16Array( arr8.buffer );
[17, -45] // two elements (decimal)
```

---

Thus, your sample would be:

```
var x = new Int16Array([17, -45]);
var y = new Uint8Array(x.buffer); // the .buffer is important!
var z = new Int16Array(y.buffer);

console.log(x[1] === z[1]); // true;
```

---

If, rather than to a `UintArray` you want to convert to a Node.js Buffer:

```
// Important to use .buffer here, otherwise it'll use the decimal
// representation of your input, not the actual bytes!
const buffer = Buffer.from(arr16.buffer);
```

Then you'll need to add:

```
new Int16Array( buffer.buffer )
```

Because if you do this:

```
new Int16Array( buffer );
```

Then you're effectively doing this:

```
const decimalRepresentationOfBytesInBuffer = [...buffer.values()];
new Int16Array( decimalRepresentationOfBytesInBuffer );
[17, 0, 11, 255] // four elements (decimal)
...<11 00 00 00 d3 00 ff 00> // of 8 bytes total
```

Comment: Maybe "decimal representation" is not completely accurate but if anyone feels they can say it in an easy to understand way that is more correct: feel free!

Comment: `(new Uint8Array(buffer)).buffer` is pointless, you can do `buffer.buffer` right away. (Yes, it's weird, that's because nodejs `Buffer` also implements the `Uint8Array` interface)

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of that, even though _I knew_ that Buffer implements it. I've edited the above answer to remove the redundant constructor. Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

To create a buffer to [`push` into a `Readable` stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_push_chunk_encoding) from a typed array, use the [`Buffer.from` method](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_from_arraybuffer_byteoffset_length) on its [`.buffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/buffer):

```
var data = new Int16Array([17, -45]);
var buf = Buffer.from(data.buffer);
rs.push(buf);
```

Your `result` typed array in the `data` event handler will then need to be constructed from the chunk's buffer again:

```
rs.on('data', function(chunk) {
    var result = new Int16Array(chunk.buffer);
});
```

See [*Buffers and TypedArrays*](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_typedarrays) in the docs for details.

Comment: result is Int16Array(4) [ 17, 0, 211, 255 ]
How do I convert back  to [17, -45]

Comment: Ah, right, "*Passing a Buffer to a TypedArray constructor will copy the Buffers contents, interpreted as an array of integers, and not as a byte sequence of the target type.*" - basically treating the `chunk` like an `Uint8Array`. That's not what you want.